# Shell command to get all the files from a complex directory structure

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I'm looking for a shell command in order to get all the files in a complex directory structure. By complex directory structure I mean that there's a root folder with more than 150 subfolders and for each subfolder there are minimum 3 subfolders.

Comment: What do you want to do with the list of files?  What you want to do with the list affects the best way to get it.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "get".

Answer (score 18):

This is trivial:

```
find /directory -type f
```

Answer (score 9):

As [suggested by @michael-hampton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68086/2613) `find` is the way to go. However a bit more explanation is needed. The option `-type` can have several values, check the man page (`man find`). Here is a quick definition:

If you are looking for regular files only:

```
find <path> -type f
```

If you are looking for anything not a directory:

```
find <path> ! -type d
```

If you are looking for regular files and symbolic links:

```
find <path> -type f -o -type l
```

*(the previous command looks for regular OR link)*

Answer (score 3):

`find` works just as well. But if you are using zshell (`zsh`):

For only files:

```
ls -al path/**/*(.)
```

For only dirs:

```
ls -al path/**/*(/)
```

See `man zshexpn` for more eamples. Specifically the "glob qualifier" section.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in bash4+ (be aware that this follows symlinks):

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in **/*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

Comment: The silly code coloring makes me want to put a comment `# */` just to fix it.

Comment: @kojiro - Sorry, forgot to force the syntax highlighter to bash mode.

Comment: Now I'm exceedingly happy I posted that dumb comment, because I didn't know you *could* force the highlighter to bash mode.

Comment: @kojiro, in case you not found it yet, see [Syntax highlighting for code](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) in the Markdown help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is

```bsh
ls -R directory_name
```

Comment: Note that this will also give you quite a lot of things that are _not_ files, including lines with colons that may or may not be part of names. Additionally, given any name in the list, it's nontrivial to figure out the name's location in the file hierarchy if used in a script. If names contain newlines (which admittedly is uncommon), then you have no way of detecting one part of the filename from another name.

Comment: Sure. However, it is not clear what the user exactly needs, as it appears from the unanswered comments to the original question. Maybe this is the right answer.